# Within item response theory, what is the $\theta$-grid?

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, latent-variable, item-response-theory

Within item response theory, the latent trait (e.g., ability) is often depicted as $\theta$. Within item response theory, I have also come across the term $\theta$-grid. For example, the description of the `tam.latreg` function within R's [TAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TAM/TAM.pdf) package package states that "only the individual likelihood evaluated at a $\theta$-grid is needed as the input" (p. 103).

I tried to find more information on what the $\theta$-grid is but to no avail. I wonder if it is comparable to thresholds within categorical factor analysis, which divide the continuous range of a latent factor into different subsets. Accordingly, the number of thresholds are a function of the number of options within the categorical items. However, this does not seem to be the case in the case of $\theta$-grids. What is a $\theta$-grid?

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @RyanVolpi, I added an example where I came across the term. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *$\theta$-grid* or *grid* is used throughout the entire [manual of TAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TAM/TAM.pdf). Even so, I didn't find any point in the manual where the term was defined. The term, however, refers to the [Gauss-Hermite quadrature points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) that are employed in TAM for numerical approximation of the integral over the ability distribution.

The term *grid* is used also by Adams, Wilson and Wang (1997, p. 5), one of the main references for TAM.

**Literature**

Adams, R. J., Wilson, M. and Wang, W.-C. (1997). "The Multidimensional Random Coefficients Multinomial Logit Model." Applied Psychological Measurement 21(1): 1-23.